# export html to docx in react

Tags: html, reactjs, export, docx

How can we export html content to docx in react js?
I need to export html content to docx using react. I have used html-to-docx library but I can export the docx to locally running application only. The exported word document shows boxes only (actually content is not shown) When I tried exporting on remotely deployed linux machine, export does not work. Here is what I have done so far

```
exportToWord(e) {
    (async () => {
      const fileBuffer = await HTMLtoDOCX(myHTML, null, {
        table: { row: { cantSplit: true } },
        footer: true,
        pageNumber: true,
      });
      console.log("===", fileBuffer);
      const link = document.createElement("a");
      link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(fileBuffer);

      link.download = "SampleReport.docx";
      link.click();
    })();
  }
```

Comment: It looks like the tool you are using might not be able to render all the HTML elements fully before exporting to DOCX. You could consider using a more comprehensive document imaging toolkit like LEADTOOLS, which has JS [document conversion](https://www.leadtools.com/help/sdk/v22/dh/javascript/dox/leaddocument-convert.html) and might produce the desired DOCX (Disclaimer: I work for the vendor of this toolkit) Otherwise, consider adding an example of the source  HTML that you are trying to export to the question so that more in-depth suggestions can be given.